# Android tablet development - Auto populate multiple non-list views from an SQLite DB?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-contentprovider, android-sqlite, xoom

I am developing for an android tablet and I have one tab which is a fragment that has a number of ViewGroups (LinearLayouts) containing a number of colored circle views - which have a number dataobjects associated with them. (see screen shot)

Messages will come in from the network and update the number of dataobjects associated with each circle view. When they come in i want to add them to an SQLite DB; and when that changes automatically update listening ViewGroups. Which will then update the number and content of the dataobjects associated with each CircleView.

I have been looking at content providers, adapters etc.. but these seem to be oriented for listviews that take up the entire screen such as on a phone. 
Question is how do I efficiently update these views automatically within my fragment based on DB changes? 
What mechanisms would i use and how would i use them. I have been coming to a number of deadends. (based on my limited android dev exp)

Any insight would be great! Thanks

Tab fragment where i set up my views:

```
    public class TheoryFragment extends Fragment {


    private ViewGroup theoriesView;
    private HashMap<String, TheoryPlanetView> theoryViewsToAnchors = new HashMap<String, TheoryPlanetView>();
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;    
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        theoriesView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.theories_activity_vertical,
                container, false);

        setupListeners();

        return theoriesView;
    }

    /**
     * Setups the listeners 
     */
    private void setupListeners() {
        //add listeners to all the draggable planetViews
        // get all the colors and the
        int childCount = theoriesView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View possibleView = theoriesView.getChildAt(i);
            if( possibleView instanceof TheoryPlanetView ) {
                TheoryPlanetView tv = (TheoryPlanetView) possibleView;
                tv.setOnDragListener(new TargetViewDragListener());

                theoryViewsToAnchors.put(tv.getAnchor(), tv);
            }
        }

        ViewGroup planetColorsView = (FrameLayout)             theoriesView.findViewById(R.id.colors_include);
        // get all the colors and the
        childCount = planetColorsView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            View color = planetColorsView.getChildAt(i);
            color.setOnTouchListener(new CircleViewDefaultTouchListener());
        }
    }

}
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

Having some trouble understanding the question but I would use an Async Task
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Basically you want to do the network or db stuff on a background thread. When the Task is complete android will auto run a method

onPreexecute() -> start a progress bar etc

doInBackground() -> network/db

onPostExecute() -> update your UI (called when doInBackground is complete)

If this isnt enough you can also look into the observer pattern